# NullPointerException problem, can't add event

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making a project where I added a calendar (compact calendar --> https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView). I have two Fragments that are sending some data with bundle method between them. One has the calendar, the second one has the form to create an object.

The second one is just sending the new object to the First one and I want the first one adding the event in the calendar.

Before all, I checked and the object sent by the Second Fragment isn't null, and I can add an Event with the first Fragment in the `OnCreateView` method.

But when I try to call the `addEvent` method after I received the object, it says there is a problem and the object is null, but as I said, I checked and it isn't null.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        Cours c = bundle.getParcelable("CoursNew");
        if (c != null) {
            ajouterCours(c);
        }
    }

    public Cours ajouterCours(Cours c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.listeDate.size(); i++) {
            Event e = new Event(c.getColor(), c.getDateLong(i),c.getNom());
            System.out.println(e);
            c.listeEvent.add(e);
            compactCalendar.addEvent(e);
        }
        listeCours.add(c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView.addEvent(com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.domain.Event, boolean)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.wllh.Menu1.ajouterCours(Menu1.java:181)
>           at com.example.wllh.Menu1.onCreateView(Menu1.java:62)

Comment: By the error the `compactCalendar` is null not the `Cours` object ...

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)